# How to fix "ImportError : This platform not supported" when using "pystray" with Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, traceback, pystray

So after I compiled the program I wrote using `pyinstaller` in `one-file` mode, The program doesn't seem to function at all. 
When I try to execute it, I receive the following Exception in a Window:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "pystray\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
  File "pystray\__init__.py", line 44, in backend
ImportError: this platform is not supported: No module named 'pystray._win32'
```

**What could be the issue here? I mean how do I solve this problem?**

I'm currently running: 
Python **3.9** 
Windows 10 **(the latest version)** 
Visual Studio **Code**

Comment: Do you know if you're using the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Python?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm running the 64-bit version of Python.

Comment: Many third-party modules don't support the 64-bit version of Python — which is why many (most?) folk just use the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the git bash or command prompt. I don't think PyInstaller works with the VSC terminal.